# error : identifier "atomicOr" is undefined in Thrust program

Tags: thrust, atomic

I have found that the Cuda atomicOr function is not recognized in my Thrust program compiled in Visual Studio 2012.

I have read that all header files should already be included when the NVidia nvcc compiler is invoked.  Most postings on this issue state that this must mean the architectural settings are incorrect.

I have tried it with these settings based on other postings:
[How to set CUDA compiler flags in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411435/how-to-set-cuda-compiler-flags-in-visual-studio-2010)

...as well as using:
http://s1240.photobucket.com/user/fireshot8888/media/cuda_settings.png.html

main.cpp:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "cuda.h"

using namespace std;

//Visual C++ compiled main function to launch the GPU calling code
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Just some random data hand keyed to make it a complete example for stack overflow while not being too complicated
    float data[] = {1.2, 3.4, 3.4, 3.3, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 3.4, 4.4, 4.4,
    1.2, 3.4, 3.4, 3.3, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 3.4, 4.4, 4.4};

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_data(data, data+20);   //Holds the contents of the file as they are read; it will be cleared once we are done with it.

    const int numVars = 10;
    int numBins = 4;
    int rowCount = 2;

    doHistogramGPU(numVars, h_data, numBins, rowCount);


    return 0;

}
```

cuda.cu:

```
#include "cuda.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>

//I GAVE THIS A TRY BUT IT DID NOT FIX MY ISSUE::::
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

using namespace std;

//Function to call the kernel
void doHistogramGPU(int numVars, thrust::host_vector<float> h_buffer, int numBins, int numRecords)
{
    int dataSize = sizeof(BYTE_UNIT);
    int shiftSize = dataSize - 1;

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_buffer(h_buffer.begin(), h_buffer.end());

    int bitVectorSize = ceil(numRecords * numVars / (float)dataSize);

    thrust::device_vector<BYTE_UNIT> d_bitData(bitVectorSize * numBins);

    thrust::counting_iterator<int> counter(0);
    auto zipInFirst = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_buffer.begin(), counter));
    auto zipInLast = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_buffer.end(), counter + d_buffer.size()));


    float minValues[] = {579.8, 72.16, 0.000385, 7.576e-005, 6.954e-005, 0, 0, 2.602e-012, 1.946e-013, 7.393e-015};
    float maxValues[] = {1053, 22150, 0.7599, 0.7596, 0.24, 0.2398, 0.1623, 1.167e-007, 4.518e-006, 5.322e-008};

    //Get things loaded onto the device then call the kernel
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_minValues(minValues, minValues+10);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_maxValues(maxValues, maxValues+10);

    thrust::device_ptr<float> minDevPtr = &d_minValues[0];
    thrust::device_ptr<float> maxDevPtr = &d_maxValues[0];
    thrust::device_ptr<BYTE_UNIT> dataDevPtr = &d_bitData[0];

    //Invoke the Thrust Kernel
    thrust::for_each(zipInFirst, zipInLast, BinFinder(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dataDevPtr), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(minDevPtr), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(maxDevPtr), numVars, numBins, numRecords));

    cout << endl;

    return;



}
```

cuda.h:

```
#ifndef CUDA_H
#define CUDA_H

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

//I tried these here, too...
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>


using namespace std;


typedef long BYTE_UNIT; //32 bit storage

void doHistogramGPU(int numvars, thrust::host_vector<float> h_buffer, int numBins, int numRecords);

struct BinFinder
{
    BYTE_UNIT * data;
    float * rawMinVector;
    float * rawMaxVector;
    int numVars;
    int numBins;
    int numRecords;


    BinFinder(BYTE_UNIT * data, float * rawMinVector, float * rawMaxVector, int numVars, int numBins, int numRecords)
    {
        this -> data = data;
        this -> rawMinVector = rawMinVector;
        this -> rawMaxVector = rawMaxVector;
        this -> numVars = numVars;
        this -> numBins = numBins;
        this -> numRecords = numRecords;
    }

    //This kernel converts the multidimensional bin representation to a single dimensional representation
    template <typename Tuple>
    __device__ void operator()( Tuple param ) 
    {
        int dataSize = sizeof(BYTE_UNIT);
        int shiftSize = dataSize - 1;

        int bitVectorSize = ceil(numRecords * numVars / float(dataSize));


        float value = thrust::get<0>(param);
        int id = thrust::get<1>(param); 

        //Look up the min and max values for this data column using the index
        float min = rawMinVector[id % numVars];
        float max = rawMaxVector[id % numVars];


        //Calculate the bin id
        float percentage = (value - min) / float(max - min);

        char bin = percentage * numBins;

        if (bin == numBins)
        {
            bin--;
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Set a 1 in the appropriate bitvector for the calculated bin
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////      

        //What I originally tried to do that appeared to have generated race conditions (using data from a file):
        //data[bin * bitVectorSize + id / dataSize] |= (1 << (shiftSize - id % dataSize));   

        //What I've been trying to do now that generates a compilation error:
        atomicOr(data + (bin * bitVectorSize + id / dataSize), 1 << (shiftSize - id % dataSize)); //<----THIS DOESN'T COMPILE!!!!!!!!!

}

};


#endif
```

nvcc command for cuda.cu (which includes my cuda.h file):

```
 "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v6.0/bin/nvcc.exe" "C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu" -c -o "C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/build/CMakeFiles/CudaLib.dir//Debug/CudaLib_generated_cuda.cu.obj" -ccbin "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin" -m64 -Xcompiler ,\"/DWIN32\",\"/D_WINDOWS\",\"/W3\",\"/GR\",\"/EHsc\",\"/D_DEBUG\",\"/MDd\",\"/Zi\",\"/Ob0\",\"/Od\",\"/RTC1\" -DNVCC "-IC:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v6.0/include" "-IC:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v6.0/include"
```

Full error output by nvcc:

1>nvcc : warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(107): warning : variable "minValues" was declared but never referenced
1>
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(108): warning : variable "maxValues" was declared but never referenced
1>
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(462): warning : variable "shiftSize" was declared but never referenced
1>
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(602): warning : initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
1>
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(618): warning : dynamic initialization in unreachable code
1>
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(522): warning : variable "shiftSize" was declared but never referenced
1>
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(975): warning : initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
1>
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(993): warning : initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
1>
1>C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(1022): warning : variable "shiftSize" was declared but never referenced
1>
1>c:\users\datahead8888\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thrust-space-data\src\cuda.h(188): error : identifier "atomicOr" is undefined
1>            detected during:
1>              instantiation of "void BinFinder::operator()(Tuple) [with Tuple=thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/detail/function.h(119): here
1>              instantiation of "Result thrust::detail::device_function::operator()(const Argument &) const [with Function=BinFinder, Result=void, Argument=thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references, int, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/for_each.inl(82): here
1>              instantiation of "thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_n_closure::result_type thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_n_closure::operator()() [with RandomAccessIterator=thrust::zip_iterator>, thrust::counting_iterator, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, Size=unsigned int, UnaryFunction=BinFinder, Context=thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::blocked_thread_array]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/detail/launch_closure.inl(49): here
1>              instantiation of "void thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::launch_closure_by_value(Closure) [with Closure=thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_n_closure>, thrust::counting_iterator, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, unsigned int, BinFinder, thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::blocked_thread_array>]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/detail/launch_closure.inl(77): here
1>              instantiation of "thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::closure_launcher_base::launch_function_t thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::closure_launcher_base::get_launch_function() [with Closure=thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_n_closure>, thrust::counting_iterator, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, unsigned int, BinFinder, thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::blocked_thread_array>, launch_by_value=true]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/detail/launch_closure.inl(185): here
1>              [ 2 instantiation contexts not shown ]
1>              instantiation of "thrust::tuple thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::configure_launch(Size) [with Closure=thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_n_closure>, thrust::counting_iterator, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, unsigned int, BinFinder, thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::blocked_thread_array>, Size=long long]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/for_each.inl(163): here
1>              instantiation of "RandomAccessIterator thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n(thrust::system::cuda::detail::execution_policy &, RandomAccessIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag, RandomAccessIterator=thrust::zip_iterator>, thrust::counting_iterator, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, Size=long long, UnaryFunction=BinFinder]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/system/cuda/detail/for_each.inl(191): here
1>              instantiation of "RandomAccessIterator thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each(thrust::system::cuda::detail::execution_policy &, RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator, UnaryFunction) [with DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag, RandomAccessIterator=thrust::zip_iterator>, thrust::counting_iterator, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, UnaryFunction=BinFinder]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/detail/for_each.inl(43): here
1>              instantiation of "InputIterator thrust::for_each(const thrust::detail::execution_policy_base &, InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag, InputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator>, thrust::counting_iterator, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, UnaryFunction=BinFinder]" 
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include\thrust/detail/for_each.inl(57): here
1>              instantiation of "InputIterator thrust::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with InputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator>, thrust::counting_iterator, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, UnaryFunction=BinFinder]" 
1>  C:/Users/datahead8888/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/thrust-space-data/src/cuda.cu(597): here
1>
1>  1 error detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/DATAHE~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00001f78_00000000-8_cuda.cpp1.ii".
1>  cuda.cu

Comment: Please provide a complete code that demonstrates the issue.  Also, please edit your question to include the exact compile command being issued by visual studio to compile this file, as well as the exact error output.  Also note that if you are doing `atomicOr` on a byte pointer, there is [no such function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicor) provided by CUDA.  (I can't tell what `BYTE_UNIT` is, since you've not provided a complete code.)

Comment: I have created a simpler example that shows the compilation issue and also talks about why I want to use atomicOr in the first place.

Comment: please edit your question to include the exact compile command being issued by visual studio to compile this file, as well as the exact error output. This should be a simple matter of cut-and-paste from the visual studio output window.

Comment: I added the nvcc command and detailed output with the error in it.  I actually used the original version of the project because I couldn't get the Cuda options to show up in a skimmed down copy of the project in Visual Studio.  I'm not sure of an easy way to format the output in Stack Overflow - it looks like > and spaces would need to be prepended to the start of each line of nvcc output.

Comment: I guess a good question is why it's printing a warning about compute_10 and sm_10 architectures after I configured the settings as I did in the screenshot and other website to which I linked.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is undefined is because you are not specifying the project settings correctly to compile for an architecture (cc1.1 or higher) that supports atomics.

You will need to modify the settings for the compile operation to compile for an architecture that your GPU supports as well as one that supports atomics.

Your compile command includes no architectural switches at all, so the default architecture (cc1.0) is being targetted.  This architecture does not support atomics, and also is deprecated in CUDA 6, so the compiler issues a warning to let you know you are compiling for a deprecated architecture.

You'll need to study the available questions and documentation to learn how to set the target architecture, and you must be sure to *not* include cc1.0, or the compile will fail.  (For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411435/how-to-set-cuda-compiler-flags-in-visual-studio-2010) that you linked, use the methods discussed in the *answers*, not in the question.  The method described in the question does not work.  And read all the answers, noting that there are both project properties places and file-specific places where this setting can be made.)

If you're having difficulty getting the settings arranged, you might try opening a CUDA sample project that depends on atomics, e.g. [simple atomic intrinsics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-atomic-intrinsics) and remove the existing code from that project, and place your code in it.  You should then pick up the proper project settings from that project to use atomics.