# cuda file error "Invalid device function"

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have a GPU card GeForce GTX 295 and visual studio 2012 and cuda with version 6.5. I run a simple  code  like

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <cuda.h> 
// Kernel that executes on the CUDA device
 __global__ void square_array(float *a, int N)
 { 
  int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
  if (idx<N) a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx]; } 
 // main routine that executes on the host
 int main(void)
 {   float *a_h, *a_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays   
const int N = 10;  // Number of elements in arrays   
size_t size = N * sizeof(float);  
 a_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host   
cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);   // Allocate array on device   // Initialize host array and copy it to CUDA device  
 for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;   
cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   // Do calculation on device:   
int block_size = 4;  
 int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);   
square_array <<< n_blocks, block_size >>> (a_d, N);  

// Retrieve result from device and store it in host array   
cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
  // Print results  
 for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
printf("%d %f\n", i, a_h[i]);  
 // Cleanup  
 free(a_h); 
cudaFree(a_d); }
```

In this code ,when I use command   cudaGetLastError (void) after calling the kernel, at console window an error display "**Invalid device function**" .How can I get rid of it? 
Sample codes of cuda kit 6.5 are being run successfully with visual studio 2012.`enter code here`

Answer (score 3):

GTX 295 has compute capability 1.3 I believe. It may be worth checking your solution compiler settings to see whether you are not compiling the solution using something like `compute_20,sm_20`. If so, try to change these values to e.g. `compute_10,sm_10`, rebuild and see whether it helps. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14413360/3242721) for details on setting these values.

**EDIT:**

According to njuffa and also [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#changes-from-previous-version) support for cc1.0 devices was removed in CUDA 6.5 so you'll have to use `compute_13,sm_13`.

Comment: Support for sm_10 was removed in CUDA 6.5, and the nvcc compiler default in CUDA 6.5 is to compile for sm_20. The GTX 295 is sm_13, so you need to compile with `-arch=sm_13.`