# Error on using atomic operations in CUDA C

Tags: cuda, atomic, nvcc

I'm working on CUDA as a beginner and am trying to execute a pre written code
the compile gives error for every atomic operation that the code contains...
for example

```
__global__ void MarkEdgesUV(unsigned int *d_edge_flag, unsigned long long int *d_appended_uvw, unsigned int *d_size, int no_of_edges)

{

    unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x*MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK + threadIdx.x;

    if(tid<no_of_edges)

    {

    if(tid>0)

        {

        unsigned long long int test = INF;

        test = test << NO_OF_BITS_MOVED_FOR_VERTEX_IDS;

        test |=INF;

        unsigned long long int test1 = d_appended_uvw[tid]>>(64-(NO_OF_BITS_MOVED_FOR_VERTEX_IDS+NO_OF_BITS_MOVED_FOR_VERTEX_IDS));

        unsigned long long int test2 = d_appended_uvw[tid-1]>>(64-(NO_OF_BITS_MOVED_FOR_VERTEX_IDS+NO_OF_BITS_MOVED_FOR_VERTEX_IDS));

        if(test1>test2)

            d_edge_flag[tid]=1;

        if(test1 == test)
            * atomicMin(d_size,tid); //also to know the last element in the array, i.e. the size of new edge list

        }

    else

        d_edge_flag[tid]=1;

    }

}
```

gives the error: 
error: identifier "atomicMin" is undefined
this happen to be a very reliable code...also i check out, the usage of atomics seems correct....please explain why the error has occured?

Comment: Ok I think your problem is following.. don't show any code, compile errors or anything else! How should anyone help you?!

Comment: sorry for the inconvience....the 1st submission was accidental

Comment: Ok, so I revoke my downvote, too

Comment: For what compute architectur do you compute? Take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532728/error-identifier-atomicadd-is-undefined-under-visual-studio-2010-cuda-4-2). Atomic operations are available since cc2.0.

Comment: i'm using tesla C2075....it's cc2.0
this code originally was compiled on tesla S1070 cc 1.3 (i suppose)

Comment: What is your compilation string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are compiling with nvcc only (defaulting to sm_10), without specifying the minimal needed compute capability. In fact `atomicMin()` on 32 bits global memory has been introduced in devices with CC1.1 (compute capability 1.1), as you can see in [this table](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__feature-support-per-compute-capability).

Try compiling with

```
nvcc -arch sm_11 ...
```

This will let the `atomicMin()` funcion be recognized. However best you compile for the actual architecture of your GPU.

EDITED: being it Tesla C2075, :

```
nvcc -arch sm_20 ...
```

should work as well.

EDIT: as required by the OP, adding a reference:

You can find a very detailed explanation of the meaning of `-arch` and `-code` options [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#gpu-compilation).

In particular it's reported explicitly that *both -arch and -code options can be omitted*.

```
nvcc x.cu
```

*is short hand for*

```
nvcc x.cu -arch=compute_10 -code=sm_10,compute_10
```

Comment: @Sigismondo your compile commands are not correct.  If you specify the `-code` option, the `-arch` option [must be](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#shorthand-2) a *virtual architecture only*.  You can fix this either simply by specifying `nvcc -arch sm_20 ...` or else `nvcc -arch compute_20 -code sm_20 ...`

Comment: Thanks...-arch sm_20 worked
can you please give me some link where I can furthur read about such issue...?

Comment: I've edited the answer, you can find there the link to the documentation for the nvcc options. Oh yes Robert Crovella too reported the link!