# Memory Race in Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, race-condition

I have a global function that get an array and index to array. 
the function need to find a word in some dictionary and where it start in a given sequence.

but I see that the threads are overwrite the results. so I guess its because a memory race. 
what can I do?

```
__global__ void find_words(int* dictionary, int dictionary_size, int* indeces, 
int indeces_size, int *sequence, int sequence_size, 
int longest_word, int* devWords, int  *counter)
{   
    int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int start = id * (CHUNK_SIZE - longest_word); 
    int finish = start + CHUNK_SIZE;
    int word_index = -1;

    if (finish > sequence_size)
    {
        finish = sequence_size;
    }
    // search in a closed area
    while(start < finish)
    {
    find_word_in_phoneme_dictionary_kernel(dictionary, dictionary_size, 
            indeces, indeces_size, sequence, &word_index, start, finish);

    if(word_index >= 0 && word_index <= indeces[indeces_size-1])
    {
        devWords[*counter]   = word_index; 
        devWords[*counter+1] = start;      // index in sequence 
        *counter+=2;
        start += dictionary[word_index];
    }
    else
    {
        start++;
    }
}
__syncthreads();
}
```

I also tried to create for each thread his own array and counter to store there his results 
and then to collect all the threads results.. but i don't understand how to implement the gather in CUDA. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that your counter is read and incremented by multiple threads. As a result, multiple threads will use the same counter value as index in the array. You should instead use `int atomicAdd(int* address, int val);` to increment the counter. The code would look like this:

```
int oldCounter = atomicAdd(counter, 2);
devWords[oldCounter]   = word_index;
devWords[oldCounter+1] = start;
```

Note that I incremented `counter` before accessing the array. `atomicAdd(...)` returns the old value of the counter, which I then used to access the array.
The Atomic operations however are serialized, which means that incrementing the counter can not run in parallel. The rest oft the code is still running in parallel though.

Comment: thanks, but I tried it before I asked the question and visual studio 2010 complain that "atomicAdd is undefined", I tried to change the compute capability but it doesn't help..

Comment: My Visual Studio says the same, but it compiles anyway ;) Does the compiler also say that atomicAdd is undefined?

Comment: And you have still set the compute capability to 1.1 or higher?

Comment: I have geforce gt 520M with compute capability 2.1.
but visual studio, I changed the code generation to be compute_20, sm_21 as you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411435/how-to-set-cuda-compiler-flags-in-visual-studio-2010
but it still undefined

Comment: Looks good so far. In the first comment of the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532728/error-identifier-atomicadd-is-undefined-under-visual-studio-2010-cuda-4-2) @G_fans says he had the same problem when trying to change the compute capability and architecture, because the project "inherited compute_10, sm_10 values from project defaults". Maybe this your problem as well?

Comment: yes i also saw that the project inherited compute_10.. so how can i disable the inherit?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I create my projects using CMake, and there the project settings were always created correctly.

Comment: ok thanks, I solved it.
after calling the atomicAdd function should i need to call __syncthreads or not?

Comment: That should not be necessary. And calling __syncthreads() inside an if-block can be dangerous. Cuda will wait until all threads in a block reach the __syncthreads() statement. But if some do not enter the if-statement, they will never reach __syncthreads() and Cuda will wait for ever.

Comment: I noticed that in the first iteration counter is updated to 6 instead 2. why? atomicAdd is need to lock the counter so different threads will not change it too at the same time no?

Comment: If for three threads the if-condition was true, each thread incremented the counter by 2, which in sum would give a counter value of 6. If you debug your code using Nsight you can only view one thread, but still all threads are running in parallel. The atomicAdd function locks the counter, but after the first thread incremented the counter and before the array access, the other threads can increment the counter as well. You just do not see the other incrementations since Nsight will only show you the actions of one thread at a time.